# Powershell - Exporting Select-String when using regex

Tags: regex, powershell

I am trying to parse multiple .Txt files (emails I've exported with VBA) with Regex in Powershell.

But the Output of the Select-String for Filename and Matches kept returning returning

```
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match[]
```

I changed the select from

```
Select from Filename,Matches
```

---

to

---

```
select Filename,@{Name=’Matches‘;Expression={[string]::join(“;”, ($_.Matches))}}
```

---

However the export sometimes returns results with the same match multiple times

E.g.

```
fsisac.com;fsisac.com  
BankofAmerica.com;BankofAmerica.com  
troweprice.com;troweprice.com
```

---

```
#Variables 
$user= $env:userprofile
$desktop = [Environment]::GetFolderPath("Desktop")
$input_path = $FileBrowser.FileNames
$output_fileDomain = "$env:userprofile\Desktop\Domains.csv"
$Removefromlist = @("1","2","3","4","5" )

#Regex

$regexDomain = ‘(\w+-\w+\.((\n(com|ru|eu|pw|biz|info|biz|org|net))|(com|ru|eu|pw|biz|info|biz|org|net))|\w+\.((\n(com|ru|eu|pw|biz|info|biz|org|net))|(com|ru|eu|pw|biz|info|biz|org|net)))’
$regexCleanDomain = '(\w+-\w+\[.]((\n(com|ru|eu|pw|biz|info|biz|org|net))|(com|ru|eu|pw|biz|info|biz|org|net))|\w+\[.]((\n(com|ru|eu|pw|biz|info|biz|org|net))|(com|ru|eu|pw|biz|info|biz|org|net)))'
$regexDoT= '(\w+-\w+(dot)((\n(com|ru|eu|pw|biz|info|biz|org|net))|(com|ru|eu|pw|biz|info|biz|org|net))|\w+(dot)((\n(com|ru|eu|pw|biz|info|biz|org|net))|(com|ru|eu|pw|biz|info|biz|org|net)))'
$RegexProxy = '()'
$regexIP = ‘\b\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\b’

#Grabs the .txt files and Runs Regex and outputs to a .csv  

GCI 'C:\Users\Powerboy2\Desktop\TestFile\ -include *.txt -Recurse  | Select-String -Pattern $regexDomain,$regexCleanDomain,$regexIP,$regexDoT -AllMatches | select Filename,@{Name=’Matches‘;Expression={[string]::join(“;”, ($_.Matches))}} | Export-Csv -Path $output_fileDomain

#List of Matches that are white listed

$OKDOM=@("ibm.com", "secunia.com", "f5.com", "zionsbancorp.com", "fsisac.com", "BankofAmerica.com", "BankofUtah.com", "chase.com", "brandprotect.com", "keybank.com", "redhat.com", "virustotal.com", "adp.com", "hp.com", "outlook.com", "scotiabank.com", "dropbox.com", "github.com", "fireeye.com", "barclays.com", "capitalone.com", "53.com", "fsisac.com%fsisac.com", "outlook[.]com", "mitre.org" )

#Removes lists of Matches from the Export 

$csv = Import-Csv "$env:userprofile\Desktop\Domains.csv"| ? { $OKDOM -notcontains $_.Matches}
$csv | ? { $OKDOM -notcontains $_.Matches}  | Export-Csv "$env:userprofile\Desktop\Domains.csv" -NoTypeInformation

#Debuging

Import-CSV "$env:userprofile\Desktop\Domains.csv"
```

---

Here is my code does anyone have a suggestion to pipe the select out and not use a join?

Comment: Can we have some sample data as well. You are getting multiple matches as you use the switch `-AllMatches` possibly. Also you usually use  `(select-string statment).Matches.Value` or some variant thereof

Comment: @Matt - i'm home now but can post some samples in the morning, its emails that are getting pulled into .txt. that contain Indicators of Compromise. 

so 
     Text.txt = Rambo.com
     Text1.txt = Google.com - sdjkasdashdaksda 192.168.1.154 
     Text2.txt = 10.0.0.5

I did remove the  -allmatch but it didn't fix the issue. I believe its because a regex is not an object initially, and needed added. Additionally some emails (.txt) will contain multiple indicators and will require various regex statements to parse them.

Comment: I suppose then you could just use `Sort -Unique` and that will spit out just the one. Your regexs looks really similar like they could be consolidated. Only be able to do that if i knew what you were trying to match.

Comment: Yeah often when looking at malware people will sanitize but doing a [.] instead of a . or just use dot they look similar because they are pretty much the same. I need to do a replace on the initial pull i just haven't got around to normalizing it yet.

@Matt I'm trying to match Domains & IP's only problem is most emails have both and i want/need both so in my example Text.txt above I'd want the output to be something like  Text1.txt Google.com & Text1.txt 192.168.1.154

Comment: Thanks for suggestions by the way.

Comment: I tried Importing/exporting the table with a Delimiter of the join ; but it breaks the table as the default export for a delimiter is the ","

Answer (score 0):

```
#Variables 
$user= $env:userprofile
$desktop = [Environment]::GetFolderPath("Desktop")
$input_path = $FileBrowser.FileNames
$output_fileDomaintemp = "$env:userprofile\Desktop\Domains.csv"
$output_file = "$env:userprofile\Desktop\Testing VBA"
$Removefromlist = @("1","2","3","4","5" )

#Regex that matches the from the .txt files 

$regexCDomain = ‘(\w+-\w+\.((\n(com|ru|eu|pw|biz|info|biz|org|net))|(com|ru|eu|pw|biz|info|biz|org|net)))’
$regexCDomain1 = '(\w+\.((\n(com|ru|eu|pw|biz|info|biz|org|net))|(com|ru|eu|pw|biz|info|biz|org|net)))'
$regexCDomain2 = '(\w+-\w+\[.]((\n(com|ru|eu|pw|biz|info|biz|org|net))|(com|ru|eu|pw|biz|info|biz|org|net)))'
$regexCDomain3 = '(\w+\[.]((\n(com|ru|eu|pw|biz|info|biz|org|net))|(com|ru|eu|pw|biz|info|biz|org|net)))'
$regexDoT = '(\w+(dot)((\n(com|ru|eu|pw|biz|info|biz|org|net))|(com|ru|eu|pw|biz|info|biz|org|net)))'
$regexDot1 = '(\w+-\w+(dot)((\n(com|ru|eu|pw|biz|info|biz|org|net))|(com|ru|eu|pw|biz|info|biz|org|net)))'
$regexIP = ‘\b\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\b’

#Grabs the .txt files and Runs Regex and outputs to a .csv  

#GCI $output_file *.txt -Recurse  | Select-String -Pattern $regexCDomain,$regexCDomain1,$regexCDomain2,$regexCDomain3,$regexDoT,$regexDot1,$regexIP -AllMatches | select Filename,@{Name=’Matches‘;Expression={[string]::join('%%' , ($_.Matches))}},MatchesExtra | Export-Csv -Path $output_fileDomaintemp

Get-ChildItem $output_file *.txt -Recurse  | Select-String -Pattern $regexCDomain,$regexCDomain1,$regexCDomain2,$regexCDomain3,$regexDoT,$regexDot1,$regexIP | select Filename,@{Name=’Matches‘;Expression={$_.Matches}},Pattern | Export-Csv -Path $output_fileDomaintemp -NoTypeInformation

#Removes List of Matches that i don't care about 

$OKDOM=@("key[.]com", "trustedsec.com", "autoshun.org", "proofpoint.com", "softpedia.com", "net-security.org", "jpmchase.com", "att.net", "SunTrust.com", "ciarmy.com", "dragonresearchgroup.org", "cisecurity.org", "gartner.com", "cisecurity.org", "bankunited.com", "facebook.com ", "twitter.com", "linkedin.com", "foursquare.com", "msasecurity.net", "usbank.com", "alienvault.com", "etrade.com", "jpmorgan.com", "tdameritrade.com", "ncfta.net", "iseclab.org", "malwr.com", "clean-mx.com", "db.com", "miscreantpunchers.net", "securityweek.com", "threatpost.com", "packetmail.net", "dnsdb.info", "farsightsecurity.com","mcafee.com", "surveymonkey.com", "badips.com", "agari.com", "key.com", "zurich.com", "morganstanley.com", "blackrock.com", "cisco.com", "norton.com", "ibm.com", "secunia.com", "f5.com", "zionsbancorp.com", "fsisac.com", "BankofAmerica.com", "BankofUtah.com", "chase.com", "brandprotect.com", "keybank.com", "redhat.com", "virustotal.com", "adp.com", "hp.com", "outlook.com", "scotiabank.com", "dropbox.com", "github.com", "fireeye.com", "barclays.com", "capitalone.com", "53.com", "fsisac.com%fsisac.com", "outlook[.]com", "mitre.org" )

$csv = Import-Csv "$env:userprofile\Desktop\Domains.csv"| Where { $OKDOM -notcontains $_.Matches}
$csv | Where { $OKDOM -notcontains $_.Matches}  | Export-Csv "$env:userprofile\Desktop\Domains.csv" -NoTypeInformation 


#Debuging
Import-CSV "$env:userprofile\Desktop\Domains.csv"
```